# Create professional edition scratch org

Tags: managed-package, scratch-org, professional-edition, scratch-org-definition-file

I need to check Managed Package Beta Version on a Professional Edition Org. I am trying to make a Professional Edition Scratch org for it. But every time I get the same error: "The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-9998".

project-scratch-def.json

```
{
  "orgName": "Professional Scratch",
  "edition": "Professional",
  "country": "US",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Did anyone face something like this? Is there other way to check it?

Comment: Did you try creating the org without some of those parameters? Also remember that it tries to create an org with the namespace specified in the sfdx-project.json file, and I don't think Professional Edition orgs can have namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use different combinations of parameters and namespace is empty

Comment: That is really weird. The documentation states that for this error message you should get in touch with customer support (so good luck with that).

Comment: O yes, I found this too. Thank you!

Comment: Remember to come back and reply to your own answer if you get a solution! :)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Even the generic sf force org create edition=Professional -a ScratchOrgAlias -n -s doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work when you update your project-scratch-def.json as `{
  "orgName": "Salesforce DX Company",
  "edition": "Professional",
  "features": ["AuthorApex", "API"]
}`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
{
    "orgName": "demo company",
    "edition": "Professional",
    "features": ["API"]
}
```

I think API makes the difference

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I'll check it

Comment: This worked for me. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Konstantin did this work for you?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but I will, thanks